# How to style something based on the URL?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a wrapper that is displaying on the whole screen and I want it so if I enter `?display=0` into my URL that the wrapper will disappear with PHP or JavaScript. I've been searching for 2 hours and these are the things I found:

```php
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($host == 'http://example.com/home?display=0') { ... }
```

```js
if(location.hash == "") { ... }
```

```php
if($_GET['display' == 1]) { ... }
```

But none of them worked so is there **any** way to do this in PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in what you were doing.

```php
if($_GET['display' == 1]) { ... }
                 ^     ^
```

You have a rather serious typo, you misplaced the closing bracket of the $_GET array.

Changing the above to this should yield some results;

```php
if($_GET['display'] == 1 ) { ... }
```

Although I personally would do a check to see if "display" is set at all, so you'd end up with something like;

```php
if ( isset( $_GET['display'] ) ) {
    // The URL included a ?display= parameter
    if ( $_GET['display'] == 1 ) { ... }

}else{
    // Default behaviour if there is no ?display= in the URL
}
```

If you don't do a check like this, PHP will throw an "Undefined index: display" error if someone opens the page without the `?display=` bit added to the URL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) combined with it's [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/has) method:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const display = urlParams.has('display');

if (display) {
  // Do something here
}
```